# time series prediction model with minute data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, prediction, multiple-seasonalities

I m trying to apply prediction at my data that is taken from the sensor after 15 
min

```
2020-01-09 12:00:00 90.82098
2020-01-09 12:15:00 90.61686
2020-01-09 12:30:00 86.22828
2020-01-09 12:45:00 82.04382
2020-01-09 13:00:00 79.90056
```

I saw some methods. Stated from ARIMAX (but I understood that I can't apply because my data have multi-season )
So I looked the TBATS but something goes wrong

```
from tbats import TBATS, BATS
# Fit the model
estimator = TBATS(seasonal_periods=(96, 35.064))
model = estimator.fit(train_X)
# Forecast 365 days ahead
y_forecast = model.forecast(steps=35.064)
```

but the first value is different and others remain the same in fact the output of y_forecast is this :

```
array([89.39551833, 89.90889142, 90.04436999, 89.97717499, 89.97717499,
       89.97717499, 89.97717499, 89.97717499, 89.97717499, 89.97717499,
       89.97717499, 89.97717499, 89.97717499, 89.97717499, 89.97717499,
       89.97717499, 89.97717499, 89.97717499, 89.97717499, 89.97717499....
```

as I can see is various for the first 4 value..and for other is constant

I think I m wronging the seasonal period.
Any suggestions?